# How many Bluetooth devices can simultaneously be connected to/scanned by a Bluetooth low energy masterl ?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, device, iot

Is there a maximum in specifications,do they start to interfer if many try to connect at the same time?
what are the modes of communication is there a secured mode or something else ? 
Maximum packet size ? 
can I send an image or a sound using ble ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit in the specification. In reality at least around a millisecond must be allocated to serve each connection event. So if you use a 7.5 ms connection interval you could not expect more than at maximum 10 connections without getting dropped packets (and therefore larger latency). Connection setup/scanning will also miss a large amount of packets if the radio is busy handling current connections.

The maximum packet length is 31 bytes for advertisements (up to Bluetooth 4.2). While connected the longest packet length is 27 bytes. Bluetooth 4.2 defines a packet length extension allowing larger packets but far from all implementations support that.

The security that BLE offers is the bonding procedure. After bonding the devices have established a shared secret key which is then used to encrypt and sign all data being sent.

Sending normal-sized images or sounds will take several seconds since the throughput is quite low.

I think you should really read the Bluetooth specification or some summary to get the answer to your questions.